# Post JSON ajax request with cors not working in IE10/Edge

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, cors, iis-7.5

**Background:-** I created a WCF service hosted in my local system IIS. Service exposes GET/POST method and cross domain enabled and can be accessed using https too. To make it accessible, self signed certificate is used.

**Testing:-** When i try to do cross domain ajax call it work fine for GET request and POST request (only those post method which are not accepting data as a json) in IE10/Edge. I'm able to make cross domain call for any GET/POST request in chrome/Firebox browser. Only it's IE 10/Edge which cause problem to make cross domain call for POST request when contenttype:accept/json parameter is passed in ajax call.

**Research:-** I read lots of blogs/mdn and get to know specification of cors in which IE does not follow cors religiously. I know cors specification does not alloe custom header/header's value due to which cors preflight aborted.

*Example of ajax request i'm making:-*

```
var postDT = { "postValue": "test" };
        debugger;
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(postDT),
            url: "http://ateet3371/Service1.svc/postdata",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var a = jqXHR;
                alert(jqXHR + '---' + textStatus + '---' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

If i removed `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` then it throw bad request error else it throw access denied error.

And method implementation in WCF is:-

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "PostResponseData")]
    string PostResponseData(PostDataTest postDT);
```

And datacontract is:-

```
[DataContract]
public class PostDataTest
{
    private string post_value;

    // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
    [DataMember]
    public string postValue
    {

        get { return post_value; }
        set { post_value = value; }
    }
}
```

If i use method PostUrl data then ajax call is executed successfully and return proper results if ContentType:"Application/json" header is removed from request.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "PostUrlData/{value}")]
    string PostUrlData(string value);
```

*I already write code in BeginRequest event in Global.asax of WCF to handle Options request:-*

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS" )
        { 
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Session");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DAV, content-length, Allow" );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000" );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

And i can't enable `Allow cross domain call` setting in IE as end user would not do such steps.

**Stuck in Problem:-** But still not able to do JSON data post call in IE 10/Edge (which are cors enabled).

***(Edited) Updates:***
IIS site where WCF is hosted have only **Anonymous Authentication** enabled while other authentication are disabled.
***Even I tried with valid certificate for https but still it is not working for IE but work perfect for chrome.***

***Request Header***

`OPTIONS https://service.domian.com/projectservice.svc/GetMultiListData HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: https://sitename.servicedomain.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, accept
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: sitename.servicedomain.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache`

***Response Headers***

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: sitename.servicedomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept,X-Requested-With,Session
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DAV,content-length,Allow
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 17:26:27 GMT
Content-Length: 0`

Please help me as I go through lots of article and blog and still not able to resolve the issue.
Your help will be greatly appreciated!

***EXPERT's PLEASE HELP ME!***

Comment: Does changing dataType to "jsonp" allow the request?

Comment: Did you try  api fetch instead of $.ajax ? Fetch is the new standar. https://www.todojs.com/api-fetch-el-nuevo-estandar-que-permite-hacer-llamadas-http/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check client-side:

- you're trying to override `$.support.cors`.  This is (or was) meant to be a readable property telling you if CORS is supported by the browser.  (see [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6acf4a79467a5aea5bc1eb7d552d72366718635d/src/ajax/xhr.js#L26) for where this is checked)
- Based on [jQuery docs for ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you might want to add `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to the `$.ajax()` options
- Use correct casing of `dataType: "json"` and `charset=UTF-8`

At server-side, you may want to try responding with specific hostname (echo the `Origin` header) instead of wildcard (`*`) in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.  This is specifically mentioned in MDN in a paragraph also discussing [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials):

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.  The above example would fail if the header was wildcarded as: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

Comment: I removed $.support.cors as it is already true, corrected the syntax for datatype and charset. And set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin specific to domian from where i'm calling service. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin - just to confirm its present on both pre-flight and real request, as well as checking its content (either echoing `Origin`, or hard-coded to include the right `http://` vs `https://` protocol.)  I also wonder if you're seeing any problems in IE10 / Edge if you use a service like [test-cors.org](http://test-cors.org/)?

Comment: How should i share you the code? I mean your any id where i can share you?

Comment: I suggest editing/updating the code in the question (If you need to censor a host-name, just use 'example.com', but it's important you don't change syntax - i.e. `http://www.google.com/` would become `http://example.com/`, not `http://example.com`, `https://example.com/` or plain `example.com`.

Comment: I updated the request and response header which am getting from fiddler.

Comment: Your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header appears to be missing the protocol: `https://` (based on request `Origin`)

Comment: Sorry for late response, but i tried with both cases i.e. with https:// and without https but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a long term solution, but you could check out https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ 
You can GET or even POST data without issue through this.
Include their link before your URL so https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://ateet3371/Service1.svc/postdata and set that as the URL value in your ajax. Like I said, it's not a long term solution but if it works then see what you can do from there.

I wish I could be of more assistance. Good luck!